Horror movie with a wheelchair-bound man with Multiple Personality Syndrome
I can't remember the Name of this Movie!! It features a a man in a wheelchair who has Multiple Personality Syndrome. 
There's an incident where he changes his personality when he gets a phone call (asking for I think the name David or Adam?) and he changes by having his head turn and back-arch and then he is someone else?
I think its called 'Shelter' but I'm not certain about that.

Welcome to Movies & TV. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When did you watch it? What time was it likely from? What country was it likely from? Are there any other plot details you remember or descriptions you can give? Anything at all?

The movie is called Six Souls. It was made in 2010 and you can see the trailer below:




I'm sure you are talking about the film IDENTITY-John cusack. There was a scene when Malcom Rivers enters a room in a wheelchair for a late night court appeal. His lawyer found a journal that can prove Malcom's multiple personality and why he committed these murders.

I agree that this sounds like Identity, but please add some details about why you think this is the film the question is talking about. My guess is that's why you've been down voted.
